# ExtJS - SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I am writing some code to educate myself in the ways of ExtJS. I am also new to JSON so hopefully this question will be easy for you to answer. I am trying to retrieve some data from a basic web service that I have written which *should* be returning its results as JSON (seeing as I am new to JSON - it could be that that is broken).

The error I am getting is

> SyntaxError: missing ) in
>   parenthetical

The JSON that I am returning from my web service is

```
{
    "rows": [ 
    { 
        "id": "100000", 
        "genre_name": "Action", 
        "sort_order": "100000" 
    }, { 
        "id": "100002", 
        "genre_name": "Comedy", 
        "sort_order": "100002" 
    }, { 
        "id": "100001", 
        "genre_name": "Drama", 
        "sort_order": "100001" 
    }]
}
```

My ExtJS code is as below. The `loadexception` callback is where I have retrieved the JSON and error above from

```
var genres = new Ext.data.Store({
    proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost/extjs_training/Demo_WebService/Utility.asmx/GetGenres',
        failure: function(response, options){
            Ext.get('my_id').dom.innerHTML = 'Load failed: ' + response.status;
        }
    }),
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        fields: ['id', 'genre_name'],
        root: 'rows'
    }),
    listeners: {
        loadexception: function (proxy, options, response, e) {
            var result = response.responseText;
            Ext.MessageBox.alert('Load failure', e + " ..... " + result);
        }
    }
});

var loadSuccess = genres.load({
    callback: function(r, options, success){
        Ext.get('my_id').dom.innerHTML = 'Load status: success=' + success;
    }
});
```

Comment: Double check your server side code that echoes the response. Are you sure it is not emitting extraneous newlines, leading or trailing chars?

Comment: Would extraneous white space break this? How can I see if that is what is breaking it from ExtJS?

Comment: Call off the dogs - it was me being stupid. My web service was wrapping the JSON with XML tags - the Ext.MessageBox.alert clearly hides this from the display. I'll work out what is wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: To completely fix my issue I had to set the Content-type to 'application/json' on the Extjs request and set my .Net web service to return an instance of my class whilst setting the attribute [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json, XmlSerializeString = false)] - we've just had a new starter encounter the same problem in the Extjs introudcution

Comment: Always use your browser dev console's XHR log to view responses and you won't have this sort of confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the JSON you included above what is **actually** being returned from the call, or what you are anticipating it should look like?  The string you included looks clean, but it looks like you formatted it as well.  I'm not sure if the space after "id": is allowed, either.  It might not be a big deal, though.

The missing parenthetical typically indicates that something in the JSON is wrong.  It could be an extra character before/after the string.  Use Firebug to examine what you are getting back, and make sure it is clear of any extra characters.

Comment: The JSON is cut and pasted from the loadexception is the ExtJS code shown

Comment: I've removed the space after "id": and "sort_order": but still no luck

Comment: Call off the dogs - it was me being stupid. My web service was wrapping the JSON with XML tags - the Ext.MessageBox.alert clearly hides this from the display. I'll work out  what is wrong. Thanks for the help

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.  Stuff like that can be frustrating to find the first time. :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?10117-Solved-missing-%29-in-parenthetical.

Echoeing two statements was the reason in my case. So check your echoes again.